# What is the maximum process address space of a dotnet core 2.1 application?

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core

What is the maximum process address space of a .NET Core 2.1 application running under Ubuntu? Can it be configured?

Comment: It depends on whether it is a 32-bit or 64-bit process.

Comment: 64-bit; is it guaranteed to be the same as it is in Windows, in all  .NET core-supported runtime environments?